# Why is this verb not in subjunctive form although it expresses a wish?

Tags: subjunctive

Somebody showed me the following statement in a German grammar book:

> Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst, damit er seine Tochter heiratet.
>   (The salesman is doing faithful service for the covetous merchant in order to marry his daughter.)

Why it is *heiratet,* when the salesman is just hoping to marry?

Is it because the author thinks the salesman can (will) really marry the merchant’s daughter? That is, because he thinks it’s not unrealistic? I thought if the salesman is doing the work in the hope he might be able to  marry the merchant’s daughter, it is more natural to write

> ... damit er seine Tochter heirate.

Please someone explain it to me if my understanding it correct.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a similar construct (with very similar meaning) where you can use the **subjunctive I**:

> Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst **mit dem Wunsch, dass** er seine Tochter heirate.

What is going on here is this:
The subjunctive is not triggered by wishes as such (though many grammar books falsely claim so or at least accidentally imply this), but by an indirect speech, or a very similar dependency.
A good litmus test for this is if you can phrase the same thing in direct speech, without changing the rest of the sentence:

- In the above example, this works:

  > Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst mit dem Wunsch: »Heirate meine Tochter.«
- By contrast, this doesn’t work with your sentence:

  > * Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst (damit): »Heirate meine Tochter.«

---

Here is a similar construct where you can use the **subjunctive II**:

> Der Verkäufer leistet**e** dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst **in der Hoffnung, dass** er seine Tochter heiraten würde.

Here, using the subjunctive II implies that the merchant did not actually marry the daughter. It is relevant that everything happens in the past so we can now what actually happens. Another requisite for the subjunctive is using *in der Hoffnung* instead of *damit.* The former leaves room for the possibility that the marriage does not happen. By contrast, *damit* implies a direct cause-and-effect relationship to some extent and therefore cannot trigger a subjunctive.

---

Finally note that a similar, archaic conjunction that triggers the subjunctive is *auf dass:*

> Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst, **auf dass** er seine Tochter heirate.

This is a fossilised construct and therefore it is best to learn it as such instead of trying to explain it by modern rules.

Comment: I see, so you say 'damit' does not mandatorily tirgger the subjunctive because it can imply direct cause-and-effect. (but auf dass, or in der Hoffnung implies subjunctive(imaginary, or assumption).) Thank you!

Comment: @ChanKim: Almost. *In der Hoffnung* does not imply subjunctive, but it can go with it – if you want to indicate that it was a false hope.

Comment: Conversely, *damit* allows the transposition *damit heiratet er seine Tochter*.

Comment: @vectory: I fail to understand your comment. The example you seem to give neither appears to be grammatical nor feature a transposition (word-class transformation). I also fail to see which part of my answer you are addressing.

Comment: I addressed your rewrites, to augment the examples. Of course it is grammatical, if you can ask *womit heiratet er*, which is especially important if talking about bride price.

Comment: Today the subjunctive is almost only used for indirect speech, and even then almost exclusively in written German. A wish or intent does not require subjunctive. Using it in such a case will make a sentence sound very old-fashioned.

Comment: @RHa: I agree with your first two sentences and do not see them in conflict with my answer. As for your last sentence, I would consider using the subjunctive in my first example (“Der Verkäufer leistet dem geizigen Kaufmann einen treuen Dienst mit dem Wunsch, dass er seine Tochter heirate.”) as old-fashioned as using the subjunctive for indirect speech (however old-fashioned this may be). In fact, it is just a case of indirect speech.

Comment: @wrzlprmft Your sentence is not indirect speech because it's not about someone saying something, it's about a wish. That's a difference.

Comment: @RHa: While it is not indirect speech in the literal sense, it is indirect speech grammatically (I have seen some sources call this *inner dependency,* IIRC, to avoid this confusion). In German, indirect speech encompasses speech, writing, thoughts, and wishes (and probably some other things I am forgetting about right now).

Answer (score -3):

*damit* allows the transposition *damit heiratet er seine Tochter*. Which makes it into a matter-of-fact statement, indeed. It seems the inverted word order that marks a dependent clause is enough of a subjugation. In contrast, the conjunctive II *heirate* may have been avoided to avoid impressions of irrealis. The conjunctive I *heiratet* is simply not different from the present tense.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by *transposition* here, but the only linguistic usage of the term I could find at a first glance is [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(Linguistik)), which is probably not what you mean here.

Comment: Can you please try and expand your **fragment** *damit heiratet er seine Tochter* into a meaningful example sentence? - Your answer doesn't make a lot of sense like this.

Comment: @Tofro, is *Er tu dies und das; Damit hat er Erfolg* example enough for the construction that I mean?